# Rails Root directory path?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

How do I get my Rails app's root directory path?

Answer (score 595, accepted):

In Rails 3 and newer:

```
Rails.root
```

which returns a [`Pathname`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/pathname/rdoc/Pathname.html) object. If you want a string you have to add `.to_s`. If you want another path in your Rails app, you can use [`join`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/pathname/rdoc/Pathname.html#method-i-join) like this:

```
Rails.root.join('app', 'assets', 'images', 'logo.png')
```

In Rails 2 you can use the `RAILS_ROOT` constant, which is a string.

Comment: In Rails 2.3 Rails.root is an instance of Pathname where RAILS_ROOT is a string.

Comment: Only Rails.root in 3.1 and later (ahh.. the case of changing CONSTANT ;))

Comment: You can also `Rails.root.join(*%w( app assets images logo.png ))`.

Comment: Personally I like the newer syntax: `Rails.root / 'app' / 'assets' / 'images' / 'logo.png'`

Answer (score 112):

For super correctness, you should use:

```
Rails.root.join('foo','bar')
```

which will allow your app to work on platforms where `/` is not the directory separator, should anyone try and run it on one.

Comment: For example, on my MacBook, `Rails.root.join('foo','bar')` evaluates to Pathname object whose @path is '/Users/purplejacket/my_rails_app/foo/bar'

Answer (score 24):

You can access rails app path using variable `RAILS_ROOT`.

For example:

```
render :file => "#{RAILS_ROOT}/public/layouts/mylayout.html.erb"
```

Comment: RAILS_ROOT is deprated since Rails 3.0 insted use Rails.root

Answer (score 16):

In addition to all the other correct answers, since `Rails.root` is a [`Pathname`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/pathname/rdoc/Pathname.html) object, this won't work:

```
Rails.root + '/app/assets/...'
```

You could use something like `join`

```
Rails.root.join('app', 'assets')
```

If you want a string use this:

```
Rails.root.join('app', 'assets').to_s
```

Comment: Actually `Rails.root + 'app/assets'` *does* work, but yeah `join` is neater.

Comment: It's usually not a good idea to hardcode what the file separator token is (\ or /).

Answer (score 6):

In some cases you may want the Rails root without having to load Rails.

For example, you get a quicker feedback cycle when TDD'ing models that do not depend on Rails by requiring `spec_helper` instead of `rails_helper`.

```
# spec/spec_helper.rb

require 'pathname'

rails_root = Pathname.new('..').expand_path(File.dirname(__FILE__))

[
  rails_root.join('app', 'models'),
  # Add your decorators, services, etc.
].each do |path|
  $LOAD_PATH.unshift path.to_s
end
```

Which allows you to easily load Plain Old Ruby Objects from their spec files.

```
# spec/models/poro_spec.rb

require 'spec_helper'

require 'poro'

RSpec.describe ...
```

Answer (score 2):

```
module Rails
  def self.root
    File.expand_path("..", __dir__)
  end
end
```

source:
https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/5259062868dcf10fbcf735d6520e6a14e15fdcdb/actionmailer/test/abstract_unit.rb#L12

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
Rails.root
```

But to to join the assets you can use:

```
Rails.root.join(*%w( app assets))
```

Hopefully this helps you.

Answer (score -4):

Simply by Rails.root or if you want append something we can use it like Rails.root.join('app', 'assets').to_s

Comment: Please delete this answer, it is just noise, does not add anything to the question.

Answer (score -8):

Simply By writing **Rails.root**
and append anything by
**Rails.root.join(*%w( app assets)).to_s**

Comment: Please delete this answer, it is just noise, does not add anything to the question and it is poorly formatted.