# How to access public folder from a model method?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I want to do something like this in the model, using public folder like a db for files.

```
all_images = []
(1..100).each do |image_number|
   if File.exists?("/img/#{image_number}.jpg")
      # add image path to the list
   end
end
```

Is there any way for Rails to "see" files in public directory this way ?

Comment: Yes. If you're using Rails 4, then you want to look at http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html.

Comment: the answer to you question given many times on SO, use search next time

Comment: Rails.root may be interesting to you: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3724527/32453

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you use the [asset pipeline](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html) and you want to check whether an asset exists, look for it in the asset folder:

```
 all_images = 1.upto(100).map do |image_number|
   path = Rails.root.join("assets/images/#{image_number}.jpg")
   path if File.exists?(path)
 end.compact
```

If you have the asset in the `public` folder, which is not recommended (for various reasons) unless you use Rails < 3 and / or built some asset management extension yourself, you can look for it there:

```
 all_images = 1.upto(100).map do |image_number|
   path = Rails.root.join("public/img/#{image_number}.jpg")
   path if File.exists?(path)
 end.compact
```

Answer (score 0):

You can access it with `Rails.root.join('public', 'img', '1.jpg')`

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to use (from rake gem)
http://rake.rubyforge.org/classes/Rake/FileList.html

Answer (score 0):

For checking if a file exist, you can use:

`if File.exists?("#{Rails.public_path}/img/#{image_number}.jpg")`

And this will work regardless of the file system:

`if File.exists?(File.join(Rails.public_path, "img", "#{image_number}.jpg"))`

To get all the existing files, you can chain `#map` and `#select`

```
all_images = (1..100).
  map { |i| File.join(Rails.public_path, "img", "#{i}.jpg") }.
  select{ |path| File.exists? path }
```