# How to split the file path of my head point gets changes?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, file

I want to split the file path according to the occurance of head point in the file path.

**Case 1:**

```
 puts FileUtils.pwd()
```

Output:

```
"/home/myhome/bigproject/now_with_bugs_fixed/subfolder/"
```

My project head is `bigproject`.
I want to split the file path from my head point `bigproject` and want the result as:

```
/bigproject/now_with_bugs_fixed/subfolder/
```

**Case 2:**

```
 puts FileUtils.pwd()
```

Output:

```
"/home/data/cloud/vz-Hadoop/bigproject/now_with_bugs_fixed/subfolder/"
```

Now my project head is again `bigproject`but there is a little change in the path.I want to split the file path from my head point `bigproject` and want the result as same as in case 1:

```
/bigproject/now_with_bugs_fixed/subfolder/
```

I want to do all this in Ruby language.Please don't use index numbers.

Comment: helps? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3724487/rails-root-directory-path

Comment: Have you tried to solve this yourself? As is, it looks like you're hoping we'll answer it for you, which isn't what Stack Overflow is for.

Comment: I don't understand  people like @theTinMan if doesn't know the proper answer then why they comment on others question. If they are so intelligient then they must help not criticize their juniors. If you know the answer then comment otherwise leave Sir.

Answer (score 1):

```
 > s = FileUtils.pwd
 > s[s.index('/bigproject')..-1]
=> "/bigproject/now_with_bugs_fixed/subfolder/"
```

Or with split:

```
> s.split('myhome')[1]
=> "/bigproject/now_with_bugs_fixed/subfolder/"
```

(Or a ton of other ways.)

That said, are you sure this is what you want to do?

If you're trying to dig into a Rails app's directory hierarchy, this probably isn't the approach I'd take, instead going along the Rails root directory path as per the comment.

Comment: You are using the index numbers. But what if my project head gets changed. Then this will not work. Is there any way through which I can traverse the whole file path url/link and compare each part of file path with my head name and when it gets same then  I can split the file path from that point.

Comment: Of course it will work; change the code to be a Vaisala holding what you want to split on.

Answer (score 0):

Look into the `split` method for ruby `Strings`. [Documentation here.](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.3/String.html#method-i-split)

One way to do this:

```
FileUtils.pwd().split(ENV['HOME'])[1]
```

This of course assumes that the path you're working with is in your home directory.

Comment: You are also using the index numbers. But what if my project head gets changed. Then this will not work. Is there any way through which I can traverse the whole file path url/link and compare each part of file path with my head name and when it gets same then  I can split the file path from that point.