# cd into a directory from a mounted Rails Engine

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-engines

I have a Rails app with a mounted [Rails engine](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/engines.html).  I have created a [Rails generator](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/generators.html) in the engine.  The generator is called from the Rails app.  The generator's purpose is to copy a set of a views from the Rails Engine, and add them into the views folder in the Rails app.

The Rails generator is working fine, but I need to refactor it using the [Ruby class Dir glob method](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Dir.html#method-c-glob).

Here is my `views_generator.rb` file, and it is working just fine:

```
class Speaker::ViewsGenerator < Rails::Generators::Base
  source_root File.expand_path('../templates', __FILE__)

  def generate_participant_views
    copy_file "#{copy_path}/participants/_form.html.erb", "#{paste_path}/participants/_form.html.erb"
    copy_file "#{copy_path}/participants/edit.html.erb", "#{paste_path}/participants/edit.html.erb"
    copy_file "#{copy_path}/participants/index.html.erb", "#{paste_path}/participants/index.html.erb"
    copy_file "#{copy_path}/participants/new.html.erb", "#{paste_path}/participants/new.html.erb"
    copy_file "#{copy_path}/participants/show.html.erb", "#{paste_path}/participants/show.html.erb"
  end

  def generate_room_views
    copy_file "#{copy_path}/rooms/_form.html.erb", "#{paste_path}/rooms/_form.html.erb"
    copy_file "#{copy_path}/rooms/edit.html.erb", "#{paste_path}/rooms/edit.html.erb"
    copy_file "#{copy_path}/rooms/index.html.erb", "#{paste_path}/rooms/index.html.erb"
    copy_file "#{copy_path}/rooms/new.html.erb", "#{paste_path}/rooms/new.html.erb"
    copy_file "#{copy_path}/rooms/show.html.erb", "#{paste_path}/rooms/show.html.erb"
  end

  private

  def copy_path
    '../../../../../app/views/speaker'
  end

  def paste_path
    'app/views/speaker'
  end

end
```

Instead of writing out every file, I want to use the glob method to iterate over all the files in a given folder.  But in order to do this, I first need to cd into the Rails engine's views folder.

So **here is my question**.  How do I cd into a directory that is inside of the mounted Rails Engine *from my Rails app*?

I'd like to replace the above `generate_participant_views` method with something like this:

```
def generate_participant_views
    Dir.chdir "#{copy_path}/participants"
    all_files = Dir.blob('*')
    all_files.each do |file|
      copy_file file, paste_path + file
    end
end
```

Obviously the first line of the method does not work, because it is being called from inside of the Rails **app**, not the engine.

So how do I change directories, from the app's vantage point, into a folder inside of the mounted Rails engine?

Thanks!

Comment: [`Rails.root`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3724487/rails-root-directory-path).

Comment: Unfortunately that brings me to the root of the Rails App, and still does not grant me any access to the mounted Rails Engine.  Thanks @mudasobwa

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up taking a different approach, and solving the problem by copying and pasting the entire directory.  This got around having to access the engine's files manually, through the Rails app.

Here are the updated methods:

```
  def generate_participant_views
    directory "#{copy_path}/participants", "#{paste_path}/participants"
  end

  def generate_room_views
    directory "#{copy_path}/rooms", "#{paste_path}/rooms"
  end
```