# Attachment not send in email of rails 2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, email, email-attachments, mailer

I am working in `Rails 2 application` where email fired after upload content and `image` using `paperclip`.

`Emails` fired successfully not i want to attached image to that emails but i tried lots but `not getting attachment` in email.

Below code used:

```
#Call from model my opinion model
Mailer.deliver_new_my_opinion(self, self.user, email)

# Write in Mailer model

def new_my_opinion(my_opinion, user, email)

    @attachments   = File.read("#{Rails.root.to_s}"+"/public/system/attachment_images/744/original/map_screen.png")

    @subject      = "You have a new OPINION question"
    @from         = "#{Settings.site_name} <noreply@#{Settings.site_host}>"
    @recipients   = email
    @content_type = "multipart/mixed"
    @sent_on      = Time.now
    @body         = {:user => user, :my_opinion => my_opinion}
  end
```

Any one have a solution.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Not sure, if this helps, but I used to send emails, in a slightly different manner

*In Mailer.rb*

```
def send_invoice user, pdf_path
    attachments["invoice_#{Time.now.to_date}.pdf"] = File.read(pdf_path)
    @user = user
    mail(
        :to      => @user.email,
        :from    => "xxx@gmail.com",
        :subject => "xxx") do |format|
            format.html { render "send_invoice" }
        end
end
```

*In Controller for sending emails*

SubscriptionMailer.send_invoice(user, pdf_path).deliver

Answer (score 0):

I don't use paperclip but this is how I send attachments in Rails 2 as an example

```
attachment :content_type => "application/pdf",
  :body => File.read(RAILS_ROOT + '/pdfs/' + quote.id.to_s + '.pdf')
```

It could be the path that you are using - the user running Rails (`apache`, `nginx`, `www-data` etc.) might not have the right permissions to be able to traverse through directories starting from `/home/` so it would be worth changing it to

```
@attachments = File.read(RAILS_ROOT + "public/system/attachment_images/744/original/map_screen.png")
```

or

```
attachment = File.read(RAILS_ROOT + "public/system/attachment_images/744/original/map_screen.png")
```

**EDIT**

`Rails.root` is used in Rails 3 and 4, for Rails 2 use `RAILS_ROOT`, have a look at this question: [Rails Root directory path?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3724487/rails-root-directory-path)

Comment: I already used RAILS_ROOT so its print from /home. Right now i define here static path.

Comment: Not quite sure what you mean, even it if's a static path that you want to use, it's a good idea to use `RAILS_ROOT`, you don't want to be hardcoding a filesystem path - what happens when the app is deployed to a different OS which uses a different file system or you move the app somewhere else? I don't believe the path should be starting at `/home` either due to the reason mentioned in the answer. Did you try what I suggested to see if it worked or not?

Comment: please check my question. I updated. I already used it in my coding..but not attached image...any idea?

Comment: let me check with that.

Comment: I did it but nothing change. Still not attached image with mail. Any content-type need to change?

Comment: is there anything useful in the logs? Might be worth setting the content type of the attachment (`image/png`) to see if it makes a difference aswell as the content type of the email, e.g. `multipart/alternative`. Other than that, is the path for the image definitely correct? You could try some debugging to see if the attachment is set properly to the attachment variable.